# HTML Script Evaluations

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Disclaimer: I'm still very new to web development in general, so I'm sorry if this is a terrible question.

Why is everything in HTML evaluated on a line-by-line basis? I've noticed that any code (scripts?) that I throw into HTML requires me to cast it to its language on every single line like so:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.text_field :password %>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
            <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>

            <%= f.submit "Create My Account", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

But why can't it evaluate the scripts like this:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f|

            f.label :name
            f.text_field :name

            f.label :email
            f.text_field :email

            f.label :password
            f.text_field :password

            f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation"
            f.text_field :password_confirmation

            f.submit "Create My Account", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary"

        end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would it not make developing so much simpler to allow for this? To me, this just makes so much more sense, but its not done this way, probably for a good reason. If I'm writing out a fair bit of code (Ruby in this case), I am not a huge fan of casting every line at the start and finish.

I get that I'm having the HTML evaluate each line as an HTML object by casting it, but is it not possible to just have it assume that every line (or some other syntax - maybe actually use semi-colons) is a new piece of script to evaluate?

I guess what I'm asking is why are blocks of code evaluated this way and why hasn't it been made more efficient?

Answer (score -1):

You can, but you have to do everything that the `<%= %>` tag does.

I'm not sure about the syntax in Ruby, but basically a tag like this:

```
<%= f.label :name %>
```

does output to the page, i.e. a shortcut for:

```
<% response.write(f.label :name) %>
```

So, you could do it it within a single script tag, if you add the commands for doing the output:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f|

  response.write(f.label :name)
  response.write(f.text_field :name)
  et.c...
```

Comment: So, I am still essentially casting on every line by using response.write. I was just wondering why its not implicit for anything within the <%= %> to be cast and separated by the \n or maybe even a ';'.